# Uploading multiple files from multiple input fields programatically - blueimp jquery fileupload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to use the blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin to store images in a server via a PHP uploads handler. I've been following this posts in order to make it work:

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API
- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Input-Fields-in-One-Form
- [Sending multiple file input fields programmatically in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897989/sending-multiple-file-input-fields-programmatically-in-one-form)
- [BlueImp Plugin jQuery File Upload : How to use the fileInput option so that fileupload() can bind new dynamically added inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896468/blueimp-plugin-jquery-file-upload-how-to-use-the-fileinput-option-so-that-file)

The file upload form I'm using, has multiple dynamically added file input fields. As an example, after adding 3 fields:

```
<form id="entry_form" class="entry-form" role="form">
    <div class="entry">
        ...
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" name="files0[]" multiple>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        ...
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" name="files1[]" multiple>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        ...
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" name="files2[]" multiple>
        ...
    </div>
</form>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <button id="save_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">Save</button>
</div>
```

I can successfully upload files from this fields using the following JS code:

```
var imageUpload = {
    init: function (selector, context, options) {

        selector = selector || '.file-upload';
        context = context || $('.entry');

        var filesList = [];
        var url = site_url + '/doUpload';

        $(selector).fileupload(options || {
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: false,
            singleFileUploads: false,
            formData: {},

            add: function (e, data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                    filesList.push(data.files[i]);
                }

                return false;
            }
        }).on('change', function () {
            $(this).fileupload('add', {
                fileInput: $(selector)
            });
        });

        $('#save_btn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(selector).fileupload('send', {files: filesList});
        });
    }
};
```

As you can see in the 'add:' event callback and the 'send' method near the end, I'm sending all files in one POST to the server, this is the intended functionality.
My problem is that the $_FILES server side variable is reaching the server in the following way:

```
$_FILES array[1]        
    [files0]    array[1]        
        [name]  array[1]        
            [0] string  "Collapse.png"  
            [1] string  "Expand.png"    
            [2] string  "Map.jpg"
```

In this way, I can't relate which image was added to which input. So, what I'd need to get to the server is something like this:

```
$_FILES array[3]        
    [files0]    array[1]        
        [name]  array[1]        
            [0] string  "Collapse.png"  
    [files1]    array[1]        
        [name]  array[1]        
            [0] string  "Expand.png"    
    [files2]    array[1]        
        [name]  array[1]        
            [0] string  "Map.jpg"
```

I have been looking for a solution to this for a while and haven't reached the desired result. Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after reading this post: [Uploading multiple files asynchronously by blueimp jquery-fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807361/uploading-multiple-files-asynchronously-by-blueimp-jquery-fileupload)

All it was needed was to save the input field name into a 'paramNames' variable to send it alongside the 'filesList' variable.

Updated working code:

```
var imageUpload = {
init: function (selector, context, options) {

    selector = selector || '.file-upload';
    context = context || $('.entry_form');

    var filesList = [],
        paramNames = [];
    var url = site_url + '/doUpload';

    $(selector, context).fileupload(options || {
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        singleFileUploads: false,
        add: function (e, data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                filesList.push(data.files[i]);
                paramNames.push(e.delegatedEvent.target.name);
            }

            return false;
        },
        change: function (e, data) {

        },
        done: function (e, data) {

        }

    });
    $('#save_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(selector, context).fileupload('send', {files:filesList, paramName: paramNames});
    });
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to manually add the array keys,

Something roughly like...

```
        add: function (e, data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                filesList['files'+ i].push(data.files[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried manually adding the keys, but I get an error saying: `TypeError: filesList['files'+ i] is undefined. filesList['files'+i].push(data.files[i]);` I'm not getting this error if I use filesList without '[]'. I've also tried changing the filesList array to an object defining it with `var filesList = {}`, no success either.